# Using moment safely for date operations

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Referring to the information [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407) in regards to safely using the moment library.  I have been using this article to clean up our use of the library as part of the process of upgrading our jQuery library.

I know this is safe, and that is confirmed in the article I referenced:

```
var m = moment($('#fromDate').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Consider this line of code:

```
 var now = moment(new Date());
```

In the context of the article I linked to, is this acceptable to do or is there a more safe approach?

Any insight, articles, etc. would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/ should tell you all you need to know. You can just do `var now = moment()`. No need for `new Date()` at all, but if you do, it should work.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by a "reference point"?

Comment: in that link I gave you, it says, quite clearly: `var now = moment(); This is essentially the same as calling moment(new Date()).`

Comment: that issue is all about parsing strings, nothing to do with passing a "Date" object into the moment constructor. Not relevant. Essentially it's saying that if you pass a string that moment doesn't understand, it will fall back to using the parser used by JS's default date object (i.e. as if you passed a string to the Date constructor), and that's prone to uncertain behaviour.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for clearing it up.  Post that as the answer and I will accept it.  ( that is what I was after! )

Comment: Sometimes to avoid the 'Now' having different values acrossing timezones, i used to always use moment() with utc() flag: like that: moment().utc()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now should tell you all you need to know. You can just do `var now = moment()`. No need for `new Date()` at all, but if you do, it should work.

The GitHub issue you linked to is all about parsing strings, nothing to do with passing a "Date" object into the moment constructor. Not relevant. Essentially it's saying that if you pass a string that moment doesn't understand, it will fall back to using the parser used by JS's default date object (i.e. as if you passed a string to the Date constructor), and that's prone to uncertain behaviour.

Your suggestion of

```
var now = moment(new Date(), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

doesn't make sense because `new Date()` creates an object, and the second "format" argument is only needed if you're trying to parse a string (and thus convert it into an object).